# onPostExecute isn't called in AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

For some reason this isn't working. I do get a response from doInBackground and have saved it in result. I'm able to see the result after doInBackground and the correct result is received, its just that onPostExecute isn't running.

```
private class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        String result;
        TextView error =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorlogin);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            try {

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[0]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[1]));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                System.out.print(nameValuePairs);

                result = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler());
                System.out.print(result);


                //System.out.println("check");
                nameValuePairs.clear();




            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                System.out.println("check1");


            } catch (IOException e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void voids) {
            super.onPostExecute(voids);
            if (result.equals("Success"))
            {validate();
            System.out.print(result);}

            else if (result.equals("Failure")){
                System.out.print(result);
                error.setText("Don't match");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("no response");
            }

        }






    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to pass the result as argument like it is supposed to be:

Check this sample:

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    TextView error =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorlogin);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (params[0].equals(""))
            return null;

        String result = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[0]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[1]));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            System.out.print(nameValuePairs);

            result = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler());
            System.out.print(result);

            //System.out.println("check");
            nameValuePairs.clear();

            return result.trim();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            System.out.println("check1");
            return null;

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.equals("Success"))
        {
            validate();
            System.out.print(result);}
        }
        else if (result.equals("Failure")){
            System.out.print(result);
            error.setText("Don't match");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("no response");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even running it like that doesn't return a result

Comment: can you print "result" directly in onPostExecute? And its not the same as in doInBackground ?

Comment: I can, and when I print the response it works and it is the same. However, when I try to do anything with the UI or use the if statement, it doesn't work (it doesn't even reach else...)

Comment: Ok, so basically the onPostExecute is running. So whats the printed result text in onPostExecute? Maybe you need  to "trim()" it to be able tu successfully use "equals()"

Comment: It prints either "Success" or "Failure" depending on the input.

Comment: I tried trim, and its working, do you know why? Because previously it wouldn't even print "no response" which it should regardless.

Comment: I am not sure why the else is not called in that case, but the whitelines sometimes causing strange behavior. i added the "trim()" in the doInBackground return. so now its working. can you accept this as answer?!

Comment: In onPostExecute you should first check result for null as doInBackGround can return null. Otherwise your app crashes in that case.